Add a multiple select of enum class values in a form in symfony
I have an entity with a field that contains an ArrayCollection of enum type. And I am enabled to built a form to display such a field in a select with multiple choices, form that must allow modification of the entity, so to display the values registered as selected value.
The enum class type and enumtype don't work, as the latter allows only one value.
The (last) error displayed is: "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor::getValue(): Argument #1 ($objectOrArray) must be of type object|array, bool given, called in /home/florent/Projets/Symfony/pantheque/vendor/symfony/form/ChoiceList/Factory/PropertyAccessDecorator.php on line 125"
The entity field:

     * @var Collection<int, GenreArtiste>
     */
    #[Assert\NotBlanck]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::ARRAY)]
    private Collection $roles;

The enum class:
namespace App\Enum;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

enum GenreArtiste: string
{
    case auteur = 'Auteur';
    case interprete = 'Interprète';
    case compositeur = 'Compositeur';
    case realisateur = 'Réalisateur';
    case scenariste = 'Scénariste';
    case credit = 'Crédit';
    
    public function getLabel(): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            self::auteur => 'Auteur',
            self::interprete => 'Interprète',
            self::compositeur => 'Compositeur',
            self::realisateur => 'Réalisateur',
            self::scenariste => 'Scénariste',
            self::credit => 'Crédit',
            self::autre => 'Autre',
        };
    }

    public static function getValeurs(?ArrayCollection $valeurs=null): array
    {
    //as these keys are not allowed, and to still get the "advantages" of an enum type array by enum constant instead of name. 
        $listeFausse = [self::auteur, 
            self::interprete,
            self::compositeur,
            self::realisateur,
            self::scenariste,
            self::credit
        ];
        foreach($listeFausse as $val) {
            $liste[$val->getLabel()] = false;
        }
        if (!is_null($valeurs))
            foreach($valeurs as $val) {
                $liste[$val] = true;
            }

        return $liste; 
    }
}

The form builder:
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
    //we get the entity to be able to select the values for the roles field
        $artiste = $builder->getData();
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::Class, ['label' => 'Nom complet'])
            ->add('pseudo', TextType::Class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Pseudonyme'])
            ->add('oeuvres', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Oeuvre::class,
                'choice_label' => 'titre',
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Œuvres',
            ])
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
      // both following choices work to fail at rendering time…
                'choices' =>  ['Auteur' => false,'Interprète' => false,'Compositeur' => false,'Réalisateur' => 1 ,'Scénariste' => false,'Crédit' =>false], 
                         //GenreArtiste::getValeurs($artiste->getRoles()),  
                'choice_label' => 'getLabel',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Rôles',
            ])
            //validation incluse dans la définition d'un champ supplémentaire
            //n'est pas une propriété de l'entité => 'mapped' => false
            ->add('confirmation', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Je certifie l\'exactitude des informations fournies',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\IsTrue(message: 'Vous devez cocher la case pour ajouter un artiste.'),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

And the controller that fails:

    #[IsGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED')]
    #[Route('/ajout', name: 'app_gestion_artiste_ajout', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    #[Route('/{id}/edition', name: 'app_gestion_artiste_edition', requirements: ['id' => '\d+'], methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function ajout(?Artiste $artiste, Request $requete, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $maj = isset($artiste);
        $artiste ??= new Artiste();
// THE LINE THAT DOES'NT FAIL
        $form = $this->createForm(ArtisteType::class, $artiste);

        $form->handleRequest($requete);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($artiste);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectionToRoute('app_gestion_artiste');
        } else {

            return $this->render('gestion/artiste/ajout.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form,   
                'maj' => $maj,     //  <= THE LINE THAT FAILS, WITHOUT ANY RATIONAL REASON
            ]);
        }
    }

The marked line is the one symfony points out as erroneous.
I tried with choicetype…

I managed to get the form for a new entity
I tried to use the selection method of choicetype (array with key/boolean value in 'choices'): it systematically fails with an error shifted to… the render on a line which has no sense (an option to the view)
without the boolean values I can get the form displayed… so the "erroneous" line fine… more I can even send to the choices parameters… an array of the enum constant that are forbidden as array keys!

How can I fix this total mess and get a select or checkboxes preselected with an entity to edit and unselected with a new one, without reshaping the whole entity, database and factory? I don't want to write explicitly the value, for the enum class would have no utility.

EnumType should work: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/enum.html -> "A multi-purpose field used to allow the user to "choose" one or more options…"
